# Block all IP except few in Windows Firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-server-2012

Multiple windows firewall rules are **ANDed** together or **ORed**?

Background:
I have a SQL database server running on a public cloud virtual machine. I have configured `allow connection` inbound rule in windows firewall for my trusted IPs and need to block all other except trusted ones. But I don't see that option.

If I create another inbound rule with: `Block any IP address connection`. Will I still have access via trusted IP addresses?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been crossposted. Please don't do that. http://serverfault.com/questions/628168/block-all-ips-except-a-few-in-windows-firewall

Comment: @Sathya I posted it on super user & then found out it is more suited for serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Firewall implements the concept of implicit deny. Implicit deny means that anything that is not explicitly mentioned will be denied. Your setup should work.